# rails: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to compare votes if they are greater than 0. And i get error: "undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass" with this code:

```
def score

    if self.upvotes > 0 || self.downvotes > 0
        self.upvotes > 0 ? (self.upvotes - self.downvotes) : (self.downvotes * -1)
    else
    ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution using arithmetic:

```
def score
  (upvotes || 0) - (downvotes || 0)
end
```

But usually if you are getting nils its a sign that you should have defaults on the columns or should be using COALESCE in the db query where you load the data.

```
User.select(
  '*', 
  'COALESCE(users.upvotes, 0) - COALESCE(users.downvotes, 0) AS score'
)
```

Comment: `upvotes.to_i - downvotes.to_i` is also an option if the `nil`s aren't unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

The anwser was:

```
  if self.upvotes && (self.upvotes > 0) || self.downvotes && (self.downvotes > 0)
    self.upvotes > 0 ? (self.upvotes - self.downvotes) : (self.downvotes * -1)
```